# Initial value for 32 bit register made using D F/F in verilog

Tags: verilog, flipflop, register

I am trying to make a 32-bit register using 32 negative edge trigerred D F/F. Here is the verilog code for D F/F:

```
module dff(q,d,clk,reset);
    input d,clk,reset;
    output q;
    reg q;
    initial
        q<=1'b0;
    always @(negedge clk)
    begin
        if(~reset)
            q<=d;
        else
            q<=1'b0;
    end
endmodule
```

Here is the code for 32-bit register:

```
module reg_32bit(q,d,clk,reset);
    input [31:0] d;
    input clk,reset;
    output [31:0] q;
    genvar j;
    generate for(j=0;j<32;j=j+1)
                begin: reg_loop
                dff d1(q[j],d[j],clk,reset);
                end
    endgenerate
endmodule
```

Now, I expect that when I include the module **reg_32bit** in another module and try to read the register using **q**, then I should get all 0's initially. But when I try to do so, I get all x's instead.

What am I missing here?

Comment: 1/ You have not told us what you do with the reset signal. You have a synchronous reset. Nothing wrong with that but it won't work unless you also have a clock. 2/ Your `if` is the wrong way around.

Comment: @Oldfart I don't want to use reset signal. As soon as I include this module into another, I want the register to have value all 0's without resetting the register.

Comment: In that case you are at the mercy of the FPGA manufacturer. Most set the contents of register to zero, but I never rely in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing a register in this way is **implementation dependent**. It will work in some FPGAs that support a global reset at power up, but in general you should expect a flip-flop to have an unknown state when power is first applied. If your application requires an initial state for the flip-flops you should add an explicit reset to your design. Since you haven't told us the circumstances where you see this behavior we can't give a specific answer.

By the way, I think there is an error in your first `if...else` block. Check the order of the statements.

Comment: That's a valid concern for hardware, sure, but "x" is likely an output of *HDL simulation*, not hardware running the synthesized result.